# Cannot integrate Windows10 in my local network - pulls IP address outside of DHCP range

Tags: windows-10, vmware, router, ipv4, dhcp

I just installed windows10 under vmware.
I'm using a router with local ipv4 address 192.168.2.1
Under windows10 I'm using DHCP, so it gets ipv4 address 192.168.189.128, which is outside of the address space of my router.
How can I tell my windows 10 to use an ipv4 inside the Address space of my router i.e. 192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.254 ?

peter

ps: my old xp under vmware is still working fine using ipv4 in router address space.

Comment: Do you actually have a DHCP server handing out IPs in the range of 192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.254 on your network?

Comment: whoever rated my question down, what was wrong with the question?

Comment: @user3647093: Probably because the question isn't to do with programming. It may get moved to ServerFault or SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

I just found one part of the answer, it is a vmware problem. I have to set 'bridged' as the network Adapter parameter instead of 'nat'. After doing so windows10 gets an ipv4 in the desired range. 
But still I cannot ping windows10, I'm working on it.

peter

Answer (score 1):

ping is disabled by default in windows 10. I enabled it in the firewall and now it is working fine.

peter